# Extracting values from a graph

Tags: r

I have a graph that is created by complex numbers from the function below. I would like to extract the resulting data points which correpond with the line from the data plot as to be able to work with a vector of data.

```
library(multitaper)
NW<-10
K<-5
x<-c(2,3,1,3,4,6,7,8,5,4,3,2,4,5,7,8,6,4,3,2,4,5,7,8,6,4,5,3,2,5,7,8,6,4,5,3,6,7,8,8,9,7,6,5,4,7)
resSpec <- spec.mtm(as.ts(x), k= K, nw=NW, nFFT = length(x),
               centreWithSlepians = TRUE, Ftest = TRUE,
               jackknife = FALSE, maxAdaptiveIterations = 100,
               plot =FALSE, na.action = na.fail) 
plot(resSpec)
```

What would be the best procedure. I have tried saving the plot in emf. I wanted to use package ReadImages which was I believe the right package. (however this was not available for R versión 3.02 so I could not use it). What would be the correct procedure of saving and extracting and are there other packages and in what file types could I save the graph (as far as I can see R (OS windows) only permist emf.)

Any help welcomed

Comment: your plot is matricial image?

Comment: I dont think so but unsure, is not a picture, however it can be saved as one I think.

Comment: `NW` and `K` are not defined in the example :( But to be ontopic: have you checked the `locator` function?